# How to re-size virtual disk with installed Linux system?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, hard-disk, size

I've got hard system configuration there and I don't want to re-install it again but I need more space now.

Current system space is 30GB.

Seems like it's not possible to re-size disk so what I need is to re-init my system on new disk and here I have some questions.

- I will copy all the data to host machine first (windows), is it safe, can I lost data (break symlinks) by doing this?
- I just make same partitions with same filesystems and move data there - is it enough?
- grub:2 is installed on special partition (EF02 GPT code) - is it movable?
- Is there another ways to make such transfer or virtual drive re-size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virtualbox images can be resized from outside Virtualbox. Run this command on the VDI:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd SLACK.vdi --resize 100000
```

That last number is the size in MiB.

Comment: which partition will be resized or do I need to add another partition after it?

Comment: You will be resizing the entire disk image, but I'm not sure if the partitions inside will grow as well. I doubt it, but if not then you can use the installed OS on that disk to resize the partitions. Let us know what happens, I'm curious as well!

Comment: `VBoxManage` doesn't resize partitions, it only resizes the ‘hardware’ of the disk. Once booted, the computer will be shocked to find that its disk has changed size, and its partition table no longer covers the entire thing. That's where `gparted` comes in. :) My personal preference is to make a *new* disk image, repartition it from the VM, and copy data over with `dump|restore`, `tar`, `rsync` and/or `dd`. It feels safer to me.